# Extending borrowed lifetime for String slice

Tags: rust

I have a function that reads in a file, and for each line adds it to a `HashSet` of type `&str`, but I can't work out how to tell the borrow checker to increase the lifetime.

Here's my function so far:

```
fn build_collection_set(reader: &mut BufReader<File>) -> HashSet<&str> {
    let mut collection_set: HashSet<&str> = HashSet::new();

    for line in reader.lines() {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        if line.len() > 0 {
            collection_set.insert(&*line);
        }
    }

    return collection_set;
}
```

How do I let Rust know I want to keep it around longer?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/27570978/155423 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/28820781/155423. **Please** try searching for existing questions before asking new ones.

Comment: I did search, but no question is able to tell me how to extend a lifetime of a reference, which is really what I'm asking.

Comment: One of those answers starts with "you can't" which is the same answer you'll get here: "it's impossible".

Answer (score 7):

> but I can't work out how to tell the borrow checker to increase the lifetime.

It's impossible.

---

The lifetime of a value, in C, C++ or Rust, is defined either:

- by its lexical scope, if it is bound to an automatic variable
- by its dynamic scope, if it is allocated on the heap

You can create variables which reference this value, and if your reference lives longer than the value, then you have a dangling reference:

- in C and C++, you better do nothing with it
- in Rust, the compiler will refuse to compile your code

In order to validate your program, the Rust compiler will require that you *annotate* the lifetime of your references; you will use lifetime annotations such as `'a` in `&'a T` which allow naming a lifetime in order to document the relationship between the lifetime of multiple values.

The operative word is **document** here: a lifetime is intangible and cannot be influenced, the lifetime annotation `'a` is just a name to allow referring to it.

---

So?

Whenever you find yourself wanting to extend the lifetime of a reference, what you should be looking at instead is extending the lifetime of the referred... or simply not use a reference but a value instead.

In this case, a simple solution is to return `String` instead of `&str`:

```
fn build_collection_set(reader: &mut BufReader<File>) -> HashSet<String> {
    let mut collection_set = HashSet::new();

    for line in reader.lines() {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        if line.len() > 0 {
            collection_set.insert(line);
        }
    }

    collection_set
}
```

Comment: So shouldn't I then be able to annotate the reference like so:

   let line: 'a String = line.unwrap();
   let a_ref : &'a str

Comment: @Cetra: You can use `'a:` (a label), however only in front of a `while`, `for`, `loop` in which case it is used to be able to break from an inner loop directly to the outer loop. Otherwise, you can only introduce a lifetime name in a function signature; as I said most of the time they are intangible.

Answer (score 3):

`reader.lines()` returns an iterator over owned Strings. But then in your for loop you cast these to borrowed references to `&str`. So when the iterator goes out of scope all your borrowed references become invalid. Consider using a `HashSet<String>` instead, which also is zero cost, because the Strings get **moved** into the HashSet and therefore aren't copied.

### Working example

```
fn build_collection_set(reader: &mut BufReader<File>) -> HashSet<String> {
    let mut collection_set: HashSet<String> = HashSet::new();

    for line in reader.lines() {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        if line.len() > 0 {
            collection_set.insert(line);
        }
    }
    collection_set
}
```