# How can I extend the lifetime of a temporary variable inside of an iterator adaptor in Rust?

Tags: rust, iterator, lifetime, borrow-checker

I have a method `make_iter()` which creates an Iterator with multiple adapters in Rust, which can be simplified as the following MCVE:

```
fn make_iter(first: &First) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = String> + '_> {
    Box::new(first.make_objects().flat_map(|second| {
        second
            .iter()
            .filter(|third| third.as_str() != "t2")
            .flat_map(|third| vec![format!("{}.A", third), format!("{}.B", third)].into_iter())
            .chain(
                vec![
                    format!("{}.A", second.name()),
                    format!("{}.B", second.name()),
                ]
                .into_iter(),
            )
    }))
}

pub fn main() {
    let first = First {};
    for i in make_iter(&first) {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}

struct First {}

impl First {
    fn make_objects(&self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Second> + '_> {
        Box::new(
            vec![
                Second::new("s1".to_string()),
                Second::new("s2".to_string()),
                Second::new("s3".to_string()),
            ]
            .into_iter(),
        )
    }
}

struct Second {
    name: String,
    objects: Vec<String>,
}

impl Second {
    fn new(name: String) -> Second {
        Second {
            name,
            objects: vec!["t1".to_string(), "t2".to_string(), "t3".to_string()],
        }
    }

    fn name(&self) -> &str {
        &self.name
    }

    fn iter(&self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &String> + '_> {
        Box::new(self.objects.iter())
    }
}
```

Trying to compile this example yields a lifetime error:

```
error[E0597]: `second` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:3:9
   |
3  |         second
   |         ^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
14 |     }))
   |     - `second` dropped here while still borrowed
```

This is understandable, as the `second` object is a temporary, and the iterator returned from the same closure attempts to borrow it, failing as `second` is dropped at the closure's end.
My objective would be to extend the lifetime of this object until the Iterator referencing it is dropped, but I don't know how.

Note that the structure implementations cannot be changed. Rust version is 1.34.2, edition 2018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> extend the lifetime of this object

You cannot do this, period. It's simply not how things work.

See also:

- [Extend lifetime of variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28820781/155423)
- [Extending borrowed lifetime for String slice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35666024/155423)
- [Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/155423)

Here's a simpler reproduction:

```
use std::iter;

fn example(outer: impl Iterator<Item = Inner>) {
    outer.flat_map(|i| i.iter().map(|v| v.clone()));
}

struct Inner;

impl Inner {
    fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &()> + '_ {
        iter::empty()
    }
}
```

Since you have the restriction of being unable to change `Inner`, the easiest solution is to be more eager and proactively `collect`:

```
fn example(outer: impl Iterator<Item = Inner>) {
    outer.flat_map(|i| i.iter().map(|v| v.clone()).collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

The only possibility I know of to avoid that would be to use a crate like [rental](https://crates.io/crates/rental) or [owning_ref](https://crates.io/crates/owning_ref).

See also:

- [Is there an owned version of String::chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47193584/155423)
- [How can I store a Chars iterator in the same struct as the String it is iterating on?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43952104/155423)

If you had the possibility of changing `Inner`, you should make a consuming iterator variant. Then the value does not need to live beyond the closure because the iterator has taken ownership.

```
use std::iter;

fn example(outer: impl Iterator<Item = Inner>) {
    outer.flat_map(|i| i.into_iter().map(|v| v));
}

struct Inner;

impl Inner {
    fn into_iter(self) -> impl Iterator<Item = ()> {
        iter::empty()
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `collect()` is actually perfectly reasonable and exactly what I need here.